# How exactly does ros_arduino_bridge work?

Tags: ros, arduino, serial, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I want to use ros_arduino_bridge stack with a different board from Arduino, so I would like to know how ros_arduino_bridge works.
Correct me if i'm wrong, but I've understood that the arduino code only receives commands and makes serial outputs, and the python code part takes these outputs and writes on topics.

Is it correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60836/how-exactly-does-ros_arduino_bridge-work?/) by [mickkelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4692/mickkelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I think that's essentially correct.  The arduino code accepts simple single character commands, and replies back over the serial port.  The code is not very complicated.

I just did the same thing you're talking about, I created a new motor_driver.cpp and encoder_driver.cpp file.  I just wrote my own readEncoder(), resetEncoder(), resetEncoders(), initMotorController(), setMotorSpeed() and setMotorSpeeds() functions.

-Jon

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2